# Failed to generate HMAC with hash: sha256 in Yii app intermittently

Tags: yii, yii2

Our yii2 app generates this exception intermittently. The issue appears to have generated from the core framework. We are not sure why it occurs intermittently.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
        $test = @hash_hmac(self::MAC_HASH, '', '', $rawHash);
        if (!$test) {
            throw new InvalidConfigException('Failed to generate HMAC with hash algorithm: ' . self::MAC_HASH);
        }
```

The fragment of code generating the error. It seems to me its a problem more related with your PHP environment, that doesn't allows to run this native function (hash_hmac). The @ is used to avoid exceptions.

This snippet runs on my system with php in interactive mode (`php -a` in CLI):

```
var_dump(hash_hmac('sha1', '', '', false));
> string(40) "fbdb1d1b18aa6c08324b7d64b71fb76370690e1d"
var_dump(hash_hmac('sha256', '', '', false));
> string(64) "b613679a0814d9ec772f95d778c35fc5ff1697c493715653c6c712144292c5ad"
```

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04, PHP 7.4.3, hash support enabled. checked with `php -i | grep hash`.

Hope this give you a hint.